# Variadic template functions - where to put base case

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I want to create a function that saves the arguments into a container.

This does work:

```
template <size_t idx, class TargetT, class HeadU>
void variadicFill(TargetT& target, HeadU head)
{
    target[idx]               = head;
}
template <size_t idx ,class TargetT, class HeadU, class... TailUs>
void variadicFill(TargetT& target, HeadU head, TailUs... tail)
{
    target[idx]               = head;
    variadicFill<idx+1ULL>(target, tail...);
}
```

But this does not:

```
template <size_t idx ,class TargetT, class HeadU, class... TailUs>
void variadicFill(TargetT& target, HeadU head, TailUs... tail)
{
    target[idx]               = head;
    variadicFill<idx+1ULL>(target, tail...);
}
template <size_t idx, class TargetT, class HeadU>
void variadicFill(TargetT& target, HeadU head)
{
    target[idx]               = head;
}
```

Error message:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void variadicFill(TargetT&, HeadU, TailUs ...) [with long unsigned int idx = 3; TargetT = std::array<int, 4>; HeadU = int; TailUs = {}]':
<source>:11:27:   recursively required from 'void variadicFill(TargetT&, HeadU, TailUs ...) [with long unsigned int idx = 1; TargetT = std::array<int, 4>; HeadU = int; TailUs = {int, int}]'
<source>:11:27:   required from 'void variadicFill(TargetT&, HeadU, TailUs ...) [with long unsigned int idx = 0; TargetT = std::array<int, 4>; HeadU = int; TailUs = {int, int, int}]'
<source>:26:26:   required from here
<source>:11:27: error: no matching function for call to 'variadicFill<(3 + 1)>(std::array<int, 4>&)'
   11 |     variadicFill<idx+1ULL>(target, tail...);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:6: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int idx, class TargetT, class HeadU, class ... TailUs> void variadicFill(TargetT&, HeadU, TailUs ...)'
    8 | void variadicFill(TargetT& target, HeadU head, TailUs... tail)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:11:27: note:   candidate expects at least 2 arguments, 1 provided
   11 |     variadicFill<idx+1ULL>(target, tail...);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Must the base case come first? And why?

Thank you

Comment: Is this using CUDA?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to remove the tags. Not relevant for the question though, it does behave this way in gcc

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you get a compile error?

Comment: I would think the compiler expands your recursive instantiation before processing the base case so this can't work but I don't know where it says so in the standard.

Comment: Yes, compilation error. See: https://godbolt.org/z/e1qd63jYh

Comment: "Must the base case come first? And why?" - Yes. Because the recursive case use the base case, so the recursive case must know the existence of the base case, and the base case doesn't use the recursive case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one doesn't work because you're attempting to invoke an overload whose declaration isn't visible to that scope. You can use a forward declaration for the base case like this:

```cpp
template <size_t idx, class TargetT, class HeadU>
void variadicFill(TargetT& target, HeadU head);

template <size_t idx ,class TargetT, class HeadU, class... TailUs>
void variadicFill(TargetT& target, HeadU head, TailUs... tail)
{
    target[idx]               = head;
    variadicFill<idx+1ULL>(target, tail...);
}

template <size_t idx, class TargetT, class HeadU>
void variadicFill(TargetT& target, HeadU head)
{
    target[idx]               = head;
}
```

[Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/bYYT1v9P9)

Answer (score 1):

At the point where the template is parsed, it only "sees" what has already been parsed.  So the variadic function, if it's first, only can call itself, and when tail is empty it's trying to call a version that takes only one parameter - the target.  But such a function doesn't exist.

With the order reversed, the "base case" is visible and stops the recursion.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can I forward-declare the template somehow?

Comment: @jlanik - You can declare first and define next